# Setting up drupal's js and css on CDN

Tags: 7, cdn

I've got my drupal site set up so that all newly uploaded files are automatically stored on my CDN (Rackspace Cloud Files).

The only thing I need moved over is drupal's core css and js (along with the css and js for all of the installed modules).

I've been reading over the CDN module and the FileConveyor daemon, but it seems like a lot of overkill. I don't need a daemon that watches for new files and transports them over to CloudFiles. I really just need a one-time deal.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My "easier way" was simply to copy all of the core css and js as well as the all of the modules css and js up into my CloudFiles container and then configure the CDN module to automatically rewrite the URLs of any .css or .js file.